# How would you make a pdf link (on your website) canonical to your local page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, canonical-link

I am working on a RAILS project where I have different PDF brochures for each of my events hosted on amazon S3, these are currently accessible through links on each event page. My issue is that these pdfs are indexed on google, and I don't mind it as long as they tell google they are canonical links to my event page. Basically I prefer to use the search hits my pdfs get and redirect them to that event's page (in contrast to blocking them for google crawler or just getting countless pdf links indexed).

I am even wondering if this is doable at all, as the pdfs are being served from S3 and I can not change their http header.

I played around with link_to helper to no avail, I assume it should be possible to tell the crawler the link it is following is related canonical to the page it is on.

I have also tried blocking pdfs using robots.txt and the links have nofollow, but google does index them despite this saying 'Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt' in search console.

currently on the page:

```
<%= link_to "Download the brochure",
            @event.brochure_url(priority_code: @priority_code),
            target: "_blank", class: "button blue" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding rel: "canonical" to link_to helper

Comment: Thanks Janani, will try that and let you know if it is picked up by google crawler the way I want it to work. most of the solutions I was loking at were suggesting x-robots tag in htaccess to noindex. just figured we're using Puma so no such file, and I prefer to capitalize on the pdf text being hit as well.

Comment: This never helped, looking to serve the pdf files through the rails views rather than linking to them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses rel=canonical for pages with different URLs but almost identical content. trying to make a PDF page canonical to an HTML page with only similar text and content (and not exactly the same) is basically moot.

I finally decided to solve the problem with serving these PDFs through an HTML page with noindex directive for robots/crawlers.